# Google Analytics VisitNumber of User sessions is not equal

Tags: google-analytics

I want to ask a question; user has a session that continues after midnight. Thus, 2 sessions were created. But the visit numbers of these sessions are not equal.Why ? I think , visitnumber must be equal.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what a visit number is, but isn't a new session a new visit? GA considers a "crossed midnight" new session the same as any other new session.

Comment: visitNumber is session number. if the session continues at midnight it will have the same session number.for example: 11.45 session A, 00.30 session B. session numbers of these two sessions must be the same. But it's not the same in the visitor that I am looking at. Why ?

Comment: I think I am not understanding. Why should a new session have the same number as the previous one?

Comment: Because current session continues after midnight. For example: 11.45 session A, 00.25 session B. If the visit number of session A is 3, it should be 3 in session B. because the session continues after midnight. even fullvisitorid and visitid are equal. only the hits are different. visitNumber of session B writes 4, but its visit number should be 3. If a new session was opened it should have been 4, but the current session continues after midnight. why visitnumber(session number) of session B writes 4

Comment: The current session doesn't continue after midnight, the part of the visit after midnight is considered a different session. I don't know enough about the various IDs to say why some are the same and some are different, though.

Comment: How are you looking at "visit number"?  Are you examining cookies to see this info or is this info that is shown in some Google Analytics report?

Comment: I export data in google analytics to bigquery. thus, I can see all data. VisitNumber is a column in Bigquery schema.